# I can't remember the data structure for a fixed-sized sorted tree

Tags: java, data-structures, computer-science

Let's say I want to find the lowest 10 values out of some arbitrary number of records. As I'm looping through the records, I add them to the structure until it has reached my maximum size of 10. After that, each time I add a record that isn't higher than the highest record in the list, the current highest is removed preserving the maximum number of records.

Or more simply, how do I process a (possibly very large) list of objects and only keep a specific number of them in a memory-efficient manner?

I seem to recall there being some sort of data structure that will do this, but apparently I'm doing a poor job of googling. I assume whatever structure it is will have a java implementation somewhere.

Comment: You could probably adapt a `PriorityQueue` to get what you're looking for.

Comment: Not exactly what I think I remembered (data structures class 10 years ago is a little fuzzy), but that should do the trick! Thanks

Comment: That being said, Sebastian's answer is a close cousin (`PriorityQueue` is backed by a heap)

Comment: In case you want a less programmer and more computer science answer, consider asking on [cs.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it would be to implement a [max-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) (a [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), for instance) and do the following (pseudo-code ahoy!):

```
List elms; // original elements
Heap heap; // heap we store in

for element e in elms:
    push e onto heap
    if heap contains more than 10 elements:
        pop the max element from heap
```

After this, `heap` will contain the 10 smallest elements.

Assuming a binary heap, tihs takes `O(k)` extra space and `O(n lg k)` time, where `k` is the number of elements you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to keep all N values in memory, you can heapify the array using a binary min-heap.

Its construction takes O(n) amortized time and taking the 10 minimum elements take O(10*log(10)), that is O(1).